# Is there a way to use a general error handling message in asp.net in a SiteMaster.vb page (or similar)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm building an application on ASP.NET IN VB as a demo and I am trying to render an error message instead on the yellow screen of death. I don't need the error message to be specific to an event, I just want to render it when there is an error of any sort. Thanks million if you can help.

Comment: So... you have an HTTP 500 custom error page? Have you *tried* looking up, I don't know, "custom error page asp.net" or something?

Comment: Hi yes, all I could find was try-catch blocks, but i would need to write them into each method. I have never used a HTTP 500 but I assume I could use that instead, would a 404 be easier to use.I am new to ASP.NET. and VB